# Spec to Create a Datasource/table in Aache Druid with empty/zero records

Tags: druid

Could you please help me to get the Druid Spec template to create a Datasource/table in Druid with zero records.

Comment: What did you try? Please share errors, logs...

Comment: I didn't get any error , I am searching for the sample spec. Could you please help me to create a sample Spec to load the empty or zero records in Druid

Comment: Do you want to just register schema with Druid?

Answer (score 1):

Druid has not static table definition. This means that you can today import data with, for example, column A, B and C. And tomorrow you change your data ingestion and change the table definition to B, C and D.

All data is stored in segments (data-blocks). Each segment has it's own metadata which describes which columns are stored in this segment.

So, without any data, there is just no "column" data known.

When I want to know my data structure of a "table" (in druid it's called a dataSource), I query the metadata of the latest segment. This could of course not be complete, but if you work with an "append only" strategy when handling columns, this works just fine.

If you are a PHP developer, you might want to take a look at this package: https://github.com/level23/druid-client 
I have tried to make it easy to query data. I hope it helps. Good luck.